# View calculate angle 360

Tags: android

I am using RotateAnimation on a ImageView
like so (analog clock hand):
(smallhandStartDgree, smallhandStartDgree+val, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

smallhandStartDgree=smallhandStartDgree+val;

but smallhandStartDgree of course is getting bigger then 360 or smaller then 0,
how can i get/calculate the correct angle?

Comment: Is the question about how can you get the correct clock arrow animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use modulo.

```
smallhandStartDgree=(smallhandStartDgree+val+360)%360;
```

though that shouldn't matter much for the animation api.